# How to pass a session variable from one object to another in Gatling?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I'm extracting session variable in ObjectA and would like to pass it to ObjectB, what is the best way to achieve this?

```
object ObjectA {
  val foo = exec(jsfPost("Request1", "/something.xhtml")
        .formParam("SUBMIT", "1")
        .check(regex("""Count:([^:]*),""").saveAs("Count"))
        )
       .pause(1)
       .exec { session =>  
          val Count = session("Count").as[String].toInt
          val GroupName = SomeCustomFunc(Count)
        }
        .exec(ObjectB.bar)
}

object ObjectB{      
  val bar = group(GroupName){
      myChain
  }
}
```

Pretty sure I'll feel stupid after seeing the answer, but so far did not managed to get this working.

Answer: As Stephane suggested passing through Session worked fine:

```
object ObjectA {
  val foo = exec(jsfPost("Request1", "/something.xhtml")
        .formParam("SUBMIT", "1")
        .check(regex("""Count:([^:]*),""").saveAs("Count"))
        )
       .pause(1)
       .exec(session => session.set("GroupName", SomeCustomFunc(session("Count").as[String].toInt)))
       .exec(ObjectB.bar)
}

object ObjectB{      
  val bar = group("${GroupName}"){
      myChain
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store GroupName in the user's session in your exec(function) so you can later fetch it (Gatling EL or function).