# How to check if variable exists in a Gatling session?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017785/how-to-pass-a-session-variable-from-one-object-to-another-in-gatling), an `ObjectA` creates a session variable, used in `ObjectB`

ObjectB will fail to execute if ObjectA fails to set the "GroupName" variable.

How to check in `ObjectB` context that session variable "GroupName" exists?

Comment: Could you show some sample code? It's easier for me to answer when I see what you're trying to do in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gatling EL has support for checking if a variable exists in the session.
so you can do something like this...

```
exec(ObjectA)
.doIf("${GroupName.exists()}") {
    exec(ObjectB)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.